# WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Revoke Method don't work

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, wso2, revoke-token, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 Revoke Method doesn't work resulting in Error Code : 401 -> UnAuthorize.

[this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OAuth2+Token+Revocation) says how to use the revoke method, and I want use this for c# code:

```
    WebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke?token=" + accessToken + "&token_type_hint=access_token");
    request2.Method = "POST";
    request2.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request2.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    request2.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + "YFnfIeUVkpW64sSysLgoqajioOIa" + ":" + "L7rtcwWDqAQ6NdsvY2ZqUTAi5wMa");
    var response2 = request2.GetResponseAsync();
    response2.Wait();
    var t = response2.Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to basic 64 encode the <client id>:<client secret> value in the authorization header. Header should look like,

```
Authorization: Basic WUZuZkllVVZrcFc2NHNTeXNMZ29xYWppb09JYTogTDdydGN3V0RxQVE2TmRzdlkyWnFVVEFpNXdNYQ==
```

If you try the curl command in the document, `--basic -u "<client id>:<client secret>"` part will be doing the same thing and if you add `-v` option to the command you can see the actual header value sent with the curl request.

Comment: basic 64 encode the <client id>:<client secret>  :  -->   it's work and return Ok Status Code thank you very much